# iframe loaded event inside $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sory for my bad English
I have page with several blocks and iframes in this blocks, how can i get contents when iframe loaded, DOM can be changed by javascript
this not working:

```
$(".container").each(function(){
    $(this).find("iframe").bind('load', function(){
        alert();
    });
});
```

and this not working

```
$(".container").each(function(){
    $(this).find("iframe").on('load', function(){
        alert();
    });
});
```

and this not working to

```
$(".container").each(function(){
    $(this).find("iframe").load(function(){
        alert();
    });
});
```

UPD:
Original html too big
HTML look like

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

iframe content updating by javascript

I check DOM update

```
$(".indicator").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){...});
```

And run my code

I try to get some text

```
$(this).find("iframe").contents().find('span').html();
```

after getting all texts load new page and do the same. But sometimes iframe not loaded yet, and I wont use event load for all iframe

If I run this code

```
$(this).find("iframe").contents().find('span').html();
```

by timeout in 2 seconds all ok, but I need not use timeout

Comment: Did you check the console?

Comment: no errors in console, event load just not called

Comment: Could you include your HTML code?

Comment: First 2 should work fine so long as container exists when code is run and no errors are thrown in console.  As for accessing contents are iframes on same domain and subdomain as page?

Comment: all work fine when I get iframe contents by timeout